# How to send a Firebase Notification when new data is available to user?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database

I have a coaching app that has a section where I can push realtime updates out to the players like:  "No Practice - Do to inclement weather, practice will be pushed until Friday"

I have been trying to figure out how to send automatic notifications when I update this UpdatesTableView with a new post.  Like "New Update Posted".

I post my updates to the Firebase Database.  There must be a way to listen for changes and when there is to push a notification out to all the users?

I already have firebase notifications set up in my app but I have to utilize the Firebase console to push these notifications every time i push an update.  Does anyone know how to automate this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by `listening/Observing` to any `data change` at a particular location in `firebase`. If new child is added to that path, associated block will be called.

In your case, you can observe `UpdatesTableView`. and whenever you post any update, call the block which will send notification to all users.

If you are using Swift:

```
func observe(_ eventType: FIRDataEventType, with block: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Void) -> UInt
```

If you are using Objective C:

```
- (FIRDatabaseHandle)
observeEventType:(FIRDataEventType)eventType
   withBlock:(nonnull void (^)(FIRDataSnapshot *_Nonnull))block;
```

**According to official firebase documentation :**

> `observeEventType:withBlock`: is used to listen for `data changes` at a particular location. This is the primary way to read data from the
>   Firebase Database. Your block will be triggered for the initial data
>   and again whenever the data changes.

And, Whenever you would like to stop listening to data changes, you can Use `removeObserverWithHandle`

> Use removeObserverWithHandle: to stop receiving updates. - parameter:
>   eventType The type of event to listen for. - parameter: block The
>   block that should be called with initial data and updates. It is
>   passed the data as a FIRDataSnapshot. - returns: A handle used to
>   unregister this block later using removeObserverWithHandle:

For more and detailed information, Read [iOS firebase#Attaching Observers to read data Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)observeEventType:withBlock:).

Also, For sending `Notifications` to users effieciently, you can use [Firebase Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device). Have a look at it. i dont know about your usecase properly, But i think this will help.

Comment: Things I am wondering:

#1:  If the app isn't open, would this still work?
#2:  How do I create a notification message in the app that is predefined?

Comment: are you using firebase notification for sending notification to the users?

Comment: Yes, and using OBJ-C

Comment: i think it will be pushed,but i havent used it so i cant be sure. Just give a  try and see if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I also stucked with same problem where I wanted to show notification to users whenever data changes in Firebase irrespective of application in foreground or background.

I achieved it by binding ChildEventListener with a service which keeps running in background. At every childAdded event data is stored in sqlited db and a new notification object is created and shown to user.

Comment: Why store data in a sqlited db?